# Adding street names from one layer to another

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, streets

I've been tasked with making a network of streets for a city using a shapefile provided to me which has no attributes other than its location and length. This is the shapefile I need to work with and is the full extent of the project.

The problem is that for our purposes there needs to be a field with street names in the attribute table. That's it, that's all we need. Just the original layer, but with street names. My approach to this problem thus far has been downloading the whole road network for my state from Open Street Maps and then clipping it to the city. After that, I spatially joined the two layers so now I have a layer with the attributes of both layers including the street name. The problem is that the extent of the OSM layer includes a lot of roads, alleys, etc, that is not necessary to the project.

How would I go about deleting every part of the network on the joined layer that isn't spatially on top of the original nameless street layer?

Currently the extent of the street network is too large and I need to trim it down to only include what was on the original layer.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new attribute in the attribute-table of your shapefile with field calculator - someting like field-name: origin and fill all rows in this field with something like 'shapefile'. Then do as you did: spatially join the layer with OSM. In the resulting combined layer, select all entries where the 'origin' field is empty and delete these objects.

Comment: Thanks so much this seems like a great way to do it. I'm kind of new to GIS and for whatever reason when I use the Join Tool it ends up appending the "shapefile" designation in the origin column to every single line segment. I have tried messing with it for a while now, but I can't figure out how to stop this from happening. I know it's something simple, but I can't figure it out for the life of me

Comment: Could you try to add a origin-field to your OSM-layer as well and fill it with 'OSM'? Does that help? How do you exacly perform the join-operation? Without details (maybe screenshot), it's quite difficult to guess what the problem could be.